# How to edit a rotated mesh in pose mode

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature

I want to edit a mesh of a rotated object in pose mode. 
But when I select a rotated object with edit mode, it is restored to its original condition.
I want to make an animation process of folding, so I could't press apply button after rotated armature.
Please give me an advice.

[image: before rotating in pose mode]
[image: after rotating in pose mode]
[image: edit mode after rotating]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select the armature, go to the **Modifiers** tab. I think you are looking for this:

[image]

Some operations (such as loop cut) may not work as expected on deformed edit mesh display, so, be careful when editing.

Comment: This problem was resolved thanks to your support!!!!