# Mesh rotates 90 degrees in edit mode due to master bone

Tags: mesh, bones, makehuman

I imported a game engine rigged model from makehuman into blender, the master bone at the feet of the character is at 90 degrees pointing forward. Problem is when I choose any mesh like hair or body then edit mode, it rotates 90 degrees away from everything else.   How to stop that from happening? how to edit meshes in place?

[image]
[image]

Comment: it seems this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6838/39620  solve it. is there a better solution?

Comment: Marking it as duplicate of the question I linked to is not very helpful. as there might be other solutions? beside if someone encounter the same problem unlikely to search for terms in that question.